# EF Core Intersect between List and Property of child element returns "ArgumentNullException"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-core, set-intersection

I am currently trying to intersect a list of IDs with a child property of my Database Entity.

The intent of doing so is to find all "Form" records that that have all of the list Ids matching at least one entity in the child entity "Location".
I believe the SQL equivalent would be doing an IN on a joined table "Locations".

The structure is as such for the element in question: (I have intentionally left out all other properties).

```
public class Form
{

    [Column("FormId"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    [Column("LocationId"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

I am attempting to do the following:

```
var locationIdsL = locationIds.Split(',').Select(Guid.Parse).ToList();

return baseQuery.Include(x => x.Locations).Where(x => x.Locations.Select(y => y.Id).Intersect(locationIdsL).Count() == locationIdsL.Count);
```

* Assume that the `locationIdsL` variable is a valid list of Guids.

The code above returns the following exception:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter
> 'parameter')    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(Expression body, String
> name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(Expression body,
> ParameterExpression[] parameters)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.ReducingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
> expression)    at
> System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> node)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)

However, if I were to manually consume the collection like so:

```
List<Form> forms = new List<Form>();
foreach (var form in baseQuery.Include(x => x.Locations))
{
    var locations = form.Locations;
    if (locations.Select(x => x.Id).Intersect(locationIdsL).Count() == locationIdsL.Count)
    {
        forms.Add(form);
    }
}
```

The `forms` collection gets the item that I expect to see, most notably, with no exception.

For obvious reasons the latter is not an acceptable solution as it would require the loading of the entire dataset.

I am not sure what I am missing here as EFCore should be able to translate the first query.

In all honesty, my approach may be wrong entirely and my I might be "anti-patterning" my query entirely, I am not sure; any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am not sure what I am missing here as EFCore should be able to translate the first query

It probably would, *if* `locationIdsL` variable was holding a database query (non in-memory `IQueryable<T>` type). The problem is that it holds in-memory collection, and the only supported operation on in-memory collections inside LINQ to Entities query so far is the `Contains` on "primitive" value collection, which translates directly to SQL `IN (val1, val2, ..., valN)` construct.

Luckily, this is enough for achieving the query in question. Because intersection of setA and setB is nothing more than elements in setA *contained* in a setB. So `Contains` based `Where` operator can be used in place of `Intersect`, and then simply counting the result (or using the predicate version of `Count` as shortcut for `Where(...).Count()`), e.g. replace

```
x.Locations.Select(y => y.Id).Intersect(locationIdsL).Count() == locationIdsL.Count
```

with

```
x.Locations.Count(y => locationIdsL.Contains(y.Id)) == locationIdsL.Count
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggested alternate query worked perfectly. 

So in summary, the reason the first query does not work is because I used a non-iqueryable interface? If I had grabbed the corresponding locations from the database based on the id list first, it would have worked? 

That being said, I much prefer your alternative query since it doesn't require querying another table before the intended statement.

Comment: If you are receiving a list from API, then there is no alternative. Alternative would be if the list is extracted from database with some other criteria, in which case it could be represented as sub query inside the generated SQL.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I may need to do that for some other queries, so thank you for also explaining why the flat list of ids would not work without resolving the objects as well!